# std::vector::reserve Invalidation

Tags: c++, memory-management, std

If I call `std::vector::reserve` to reserve a certain amount of memory for my vector, will this memory remain allocated until I destroy my `vector` or are there any method calls (perhaps `clear`) that will free my reserved memory?

**Edit**: I will be reusing the container a large number of times so for performance reason I want to avoid memory allocations. It is for this reason I reserve memory up front so I want to be certain I do nothing to lose the allocated memory.

Comment: A `swap` with an empty vector will.

Comment: A simple `push_back` may free the memory that you reserve if you exceed the capacity. Why are you asking? Are you trying to save memory, or do you plan on having external references to elements inside a vector?

Comment: @jrok `swap` has constant time complexity. This means it must be implemented in terms of swapping the pointers to the underlying array. This means it will not change the capacity.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Correct. However, if the capacity is exceeded during a `push_back`, the amount of memory freed that way is 0.

Comment: @Oswald http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=71245659cb3d730b6c2b5e93eac00db4-3725be9f9ce62f113fc473b4ae69c419 Maybe I didn't express myself well.

Comment: @Oswald Why zero? The vector may move the data into a copy of its internal buffer with added capacity, and then delete the old buffer. This would invalidate all external references to elements of the vector.

Comment: @jrok Problem is, that `v` is now empty. I doubt that this is the intention of doron.

Comment: @Oswald It probably isn't. But OP asks what operations can cause a change in capacity. I just listed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: I will be reusing the container a large number of times so for performance reason I want to avoid memory allocations. It is for this reason I reserve memory up front so I want to be certain I do nothing to lose the allocated memory.

You need only to avoid two things:

1.
[shrink_to_fit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit), but it is only a request to free memory, it is not a must for vector to actually do this.

2.
Only `swap` with empty vector will change capacity for sure (see See [ideone](http://ideone.com/fjAbtx)):

```
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(100);
vector<int>().swap(v);
ASSERT(v.capacity() == 0);
```

Neither [pop_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back), [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) nor [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) to smaller size will reduce vector capacity.

BTW, consider to use [std::array<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 3):

`clear` only affects the size, not the capacity. `shrink_to_fit` in C++11 may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I believe he is actually *not* looking for `shrink_to_fit`, but rather avoid the vector capacity shrinking